# Heroku Application Error. Runs locally fine

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm building a NodeJS app. I've published it to Heroku, but when accessed at the provided subdomain fsmhvocab.herokuapp.com I get an 'Application Error'. My logs say:

`'2015-03-14T14:46:42.627038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fsmhvocab.herokuapp.com request_id=5a139cdc-0984-4c9b-b598-f280dfb2922a fwd="174.57.53.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-03-14T14:46:42.877396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fsmhvocab.herokuapp.com request_id=8d3b0200-7f7c-474d-810e-0b85930dde6a fwd="174.57.53.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Isaacs-MacBook-Air:dictapi Isaac$'`

You can look at my code on github at https://github.com/zeekw/dictapi

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you show us the part of your code that generates the error? A minimal example would be the best.

Comment: I don't know what part of the code. It happens on all of my routes.

Comment: The thing is, the site is not designed to review/debug your code but to answer specific questions. See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/